# MySQL get newest data of user from every table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have 6 tables to store my user data

tbl_user_name

```
uuid | username | date (unix time)
-----------------------------------------
  0  |  lisha.s     |  1489857236
  1  |  titami      |  1485853232
  2  |  mathew      |  1442853636 <----|> Users can change their username
  3  |  sandarjun   |  1489857239      |> so i need to get the uuid by the
  2  |  mathew_kar  |  1575456274 <----|> newest username which is given
```

tbl_user_fullname:

```
uuid |    fullname      | date (unix time)
-----------------------------------------
  0  |  Lisha Simonette |  1489857236
  1  |  Titus Amiran    |  1481256345
  2  |  Mathew Karolina |  1489234455
  3  |  Sandhya Arjun   |  1489857239
  0  |  Lisha Karolina  |  1599999999
```

tbl_user_website:

```
uuid | website  | date (unix time)
-----------------------------------------
  0  |  google.com        |  1489857236
  1  |  titusamiran.com   |  1489855234
  2  |  mathewk.net       |  1489857432
  3  |  blod.sandhya.info |  1489857239
```

tbl_user_birthdate:

```
uuid |   birthdate   | date (unix time)
-----------------------------------------
  0  |  02-05-1991   |  1489857236
  1  |  05-08-1980   |  1489857123
  2  |  09-09-1992   |  1489851334
  3  |  17-02-1998   |  1489857239
```

tbl_user_follower:

```
uuid |   follower_uuid
-----------------------
  0  |  4  
  1  |  8  
  2  |  0 
  3  |  4
  3  |  2
  3  |  1
```

tbl_user_online:

```
uuid |   last_seen (unix time)
-----------------------
  0  |  1489855334  
  1  |  1589851111  
  2  |  1689857234
  3  |  1789834539
```

i want to collect the uuid, the fullname, the website, the birthdate and the number of followers by a user with a given username. (i need to get the newest uuid of a username because the user can change the username).

The date column is the timestamp when they changes a value. for example in `tbl_user_fullname`: Lisha Simonette (uuid 0) married Mathew Karolina (uuid 2) so i neet to get the new fullname of Lisha (uuid 0) by the date column. And so on ... for `tbl_user_website` and `tbl_user_birthdate` .. even if they dont change their birthday often ;)

From the table `tbl_user_online` i only need the last_seen timestamp.

The value i give to the query is the username. the username should give out the uuid with which i can query the other tables.

Thank you very much for your help and sorry for my bad english ;)

Comment: Why does every table have a timestamp associated with it?  Have you tried something yet?

Comment: Every table has a timestamp because users can change values like username and fullname. so i need to get the latest value by the timestamp.

Comment: Why would you ever need to retrieve what their username **used** to be though? Can't you just run an `UPDATE` instead of appending new rows?

Comment: I don't it's desirable to be storing `NULL` initially for the timestamp then.  It would be better to always put a timestamp there.

Comment: @ObsidianAge No i dont want to update or delete rows. i always want to keep these informations.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen You're right. I just forgot to enter a timestamp in some rows ;) I updated it ;)

Comment: What would the desired result look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below query will resolve the question asked:

```
SELECT usr.uuid,
       ful.fullname,
       web.website,
       brt.birthdate,
       COUNT(fol.follower_uuid)
  FROM tbl_user_name       usr
  JOIN tbl_full_name       ful ON ful.uuid = usr.uuid
  LEFT JOIN                
       tbl_full_name      ful2 ON ful2.uuid = ful.uuid
                              AND ful2.time_stamp > ful.time_stamp
  JOIN tbl_user_website    web ON web.uuid = usr.uuid
  LEFT JOIN                
       tbl_user_website   web2 ON web2.uuid = web.uuid
                              AND web2.time_stamp > web.time_stamp
  JOIN tbl_user_birthdate  brt ON brt.uuid = usr.uuid
  LEFT JOIN 
       tbl_user_birthdate brt2 ON brt2.uuid = brt.uuid
                              AND brt2.time_stamp > brt.time_stamp
  JOIN tbl_user_follower   fol ON fol.uuid = usr.uuid
 WHERE usr.username = 'jack_2'
   AND ful2.uuid IS NULL
   AND web2.uuid IS NULL
   AND brt2.uuid IS NULL
 GROUP BY
       usr.uuid,
       ful.fullname,
       web.website,
       brt.birthdate
```

This query works by isolating the latest timestamp in a table that shares a common element in a row. In this case the uuid.

[Here is the fiddle to see it working.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/412c1f/3/0)

[Here is a fiddle without the username filter](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/412c1f/10/0)

You have a bigger issue that you need to resolve, however. You should not be storing values like you are with timestamps.

I suggest you look into [table triggers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/triggers.html) for update and insert statements. You should have a trigger set up to automatically insert an entry into an audit table that stores this information while keeping your core functioning tables small and orderly.

e.g create a table called tbl_user_name_audit. Have a trigger on tbl_user_name for updates. When a username is updated the previous value is inserted into the tbl_user_name_audit table with a before and after value as well as a timestamp and audit type (INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE).

Comment: thank you very much for your help! im new in mysql. but why i cant replace 'WHERE username = @p_user_name' with this :WHERE username = 'myusername' ?

Comment: Try it again now. It was in TSQL it should now be in mySQL and should let you change the username.

Comment: sorry but im getting no results if i type a username that exists

Comment: Are you sure you are putting in the username and not the full name? if you check the SQLfiddle I posted it has a username inserted instead of the parameter you had issues with

Comment: Do you get any results if you take out the username where clause? I added a fiddle with the filter removed.

Comment: no i dont get any results even if i remote the where clause

Comment: Then your tables are either empty or different than you presented them here. Can you see it working in the fiddle? Compare your tables to those I posted and then you can identify the issue.